# How to derive the execution time growth rate(Big O)?

Tags: c++, testing

So I have the following code and I need to derive the execution time growth rate, however I have no idea where to start. My question is, how do I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
// function to merge two sorted arrays
int merge (int smax, char sArray[], int tmax, char tArray[], char target[])
{
    int m, s, t;
    for (m = s = t = 0; s < smax && t < tmax;  m++)     
    {
        if (sArray[s] <= tArray[t]) 
        {
            target[m] = sArray[s];
            s++;
        }
        else
        {
            target[m] = tArray[t];
            t++;
        }
    }
    int compCount = m;
    for (; s < smax; m++)
    {
        target[m] = sArray[s++];
    }
    for (; t < tmax; m++)
    {
        target[m] = tArray[t++];
    }
    return compCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple.

Look, the first `for` loop increases either `s` or `t` at each iteration, so it's `O(smax + tmax)`. The second loop is obviously `O(smax)`, the third is `O(tmax)`. Altogether we get `O(smax + tmax)`.

(There exist some cleverer ways to prove, but I've intentionally left them out.)

Answer (score 0):

All loops are bounded in number of iterations by (smax + tmax). So you could say the algorithm is `O( max(smax,tmax) )` or `O( smax +tmax)`.